# The project uses Gradle 2.14.1 which is incompatible with Android Studio 2020.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-properties

While following udacity's advanced android application development course, I faced that problem in chapter 2 where I was asked to clone the "Android_me" project from their github repo, I did the same steps I was supposed to do but android studio throws an error saying **The project uses Gradle 2.14.1 which is incompatible with Android Studio 2020.3.** I tried upgrading gradle version as well as classpath almost everything i can do, but still it's still showing me different errors, Also saw the same question for a different project but got no hint.
**P.s.:** I have android studio version 2020.3 and the project was build 5 years ago.

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend that you use newer educational resources.

Comment: Additionally, you should use the latest Android Studio as well if you are still using that 2020 version.

Comment: Sagar, you can update your Gradle version in 4 versions, and update the latest JDK 11.It would be helpful if you have posted your error logs......

Comment: The application development course you use is simply outdated.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
}